# Findstr retuns an errorlevel code incorrect?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, findstr

There is a file named myfile.txt contains the string "hpxu"

Enter command prompt and I typing:

```
findstr khry myfile.txt & echo %errorlevel%
```

At first execution result is 0
at the second and subsequent executions result is 1.

What is wrong?
That happens on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

On first run the `errorlevel` value is not being expanded to the runtime value.

In the second, the value of your first command is expanded.

In your command, you need to tell cmd to `!expand!` the value of `%variable/errorlevel%` at runtime, otherwise it will assume the current value, which occurs in the first and second

You can tell cmd (command line interpreter) to do it using [`/v:on |or| /v`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html):

```
 cmd /v /c "findstr khry myfile.txt & echo\!errorlevel!"
```

In bat file use [`EnableDelayedExpansion`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)

```
@echo off 

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

findstr khry myfile.txt & echo\!errorlevel!
```

Try to take some time to better understand how cmd works in this answer below from [@dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053), and pay special attention to **Phase 5**:

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts#:%7E:text=https%3A//stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/8177207)

> - Batch Scripts Parser
>   **Phase 5) Delayed Expansion:** Only if delayed expansion is on, the command is not in a [parenthesized block on either side of a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318/1012053), and the command is not a ["naked" batch script](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7761) (script name without parentheses, CALL, command concatenation, or pipe).
> - Command Line Parser:
>   **Phase 5) Delayed Expansion:** only if DelayedExpansion is enabled:

Comment: "On first run the `errorlevel` value is not being expanded to the runtime value." – But why? I heard in `cmd.exe` environment variable references and such are expanded when the line is parsed, not when it is executed. Is it true? Is it the explanation?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for comment, see the actual edit and the linked answer..

Comment: The command line interpreter won’t pick it for you, if you need the value of “updated” runtime !variables!, you need tel to cmd. There isn’t one because it happen, that’s how it work..

Comment: That works for me. First i added in my batch "setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion" and next I replaced the test IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 with IF "!ERRORLEVEL!" == "0" after the search findstr ... Good job, thanks @lo-ol